# Are multipole fields, multipole expansion, and multipole radiation the same thing?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, terminology, field-theory, multipole-expansion

Interaction between electromagnetic radiation and nuclei can be written in terms of multipole radiation. Are [multipole fields](http://www.google.com/search?q=multipole+fields), [multipole expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) and [multipole radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation) the same thing?

I have found this topics in Nuclear physics book written by R.R. Roy and B.P. Nigam.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing, but in nuclear physics they are related in the following way:

You use the mathemtical technique of [multiploe expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) to find out what the electromagnetic field of your nucleus looks like, which, I guess, is what you mean by *multipole fields* although I have not heard that term before.

You then use those properties you have found to compute specific aspects of the electromagnetic radiation that is emitted/absorbed by the nucleus or between states of the nucleus. This radiation is called multipole radiation and it is a very deep, interesting and complex field.